# I want to show percentage

Tags: r

What should i write in summarise for showing de percentaje of Amount of Accidents. Thanks

```
dfc %>% 
  group_by(Urban_or_Rural_Area) %>% 
  summarise(
    Accidents = mean(Number_of_Casualties), 
    `Amount of Accidents` = n()
  )
```

Comment: perhaps `... %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(Pct = \`Amount of Accidents\` / sum(\`Amount of Accidents\`))`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a dupe somewhere, but ...

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(Amt = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Pct = 100 * Amt / sum(Amt))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     cyl   Amt   Pct
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1     4    11  34.4
# 2     6     7  21.9
# 3     8    14  43.8
```